# Best way to run power to mobile home

Tags: electrical, wiring, receptacle

[image]I  have 3 feeder wires coming up underground from the meter and main disconnect. They tie in to a 50amp receptacle box and a 6 AWG cord With 8Awg ground all in one. That cord goes into my electrical panel where the grounds and neutrals are mixed and bonded.

As far as I know the green ground connects to the RV type receptacle box and goes nowhere except that it came with the cord. There is no ground at the meter or disconnect.

The house has no grounding system, as I can not locate as much as a grounded water pipe.

I can install 2 ground rods or maybe the ground wire to the water pipes was disconnected or cut.

The 3 wire feeders leave the disconnect in conduit and I see no conduit coming out, just three wires. Perhaps the conduit is below the ground somewhere. It is a 30 foot run with 6AWG wire.

What I need to know is: what Would be the best way to waterproof the connections and get them into my panel, not just replacing the RV type of box and 50 amp cord that lays on the ground with just loose wires running into it?

That is why it was damaged in the first place  when the sewer backed up and corroded the receptacle and cord.

It was fine for years, but what are my options?

The disconnect is 100 Amp, as is my service panel. The home was installed in 1978.
Can I just put conduit over the wires that come out of the ground and use a weather tight box. Should I replace the whole cord or just cut it and replace the plug end.
Where should I install the grounds at. The meter disconnect or at my home.
I think someone changed out the main panel as it is tag as being a sub panel with a main disconnect outside  not a service  entrance.

I just checked the furnace it is 55amp minimum the water heater is 30Amp with a electric range and dryer and lights and receptacles also A 220a/c and 2 120A/C s in the summer time.
I would not want to use a 50Amp power cord would i

Would I be able to use the 100Amp service disconnect and 100amp panel  I believe the  service entry cables are6/2 4/0 with no ground in sight  no grounding rods nothing.  I rent the lot but own the home
Would I or the landlord be responsible for the upgrade in lima,ohio. Should I upgrade to a 150amp panel with a 200amp disconnect outside how do I calculate the loads in the home to figure out what I need

The flood and the over current has burned one side of the 50 Amp cord completely out

I don't know what year the home was installed on this lot or if it was inspected as it is not even properly set up on it's foundation piers  it's just one mess after another.

Thanks guys for your patience

Comment: What year was this installed? We must meet the code at the time of the install.  3 ea #6 and a #8 ground sounds correct

Comment: It was manufactured in 1978

Comment: Would it be possible to splice the wires and hard wire that into 
my breaker box. Or should I replace what's there

Comment: At that age it has done great. I use an anti oxide compound noalox or deox , even a dielectric grease will help reduce corrosion at the clamps. 
Back when this was installed only a single ground was required, we used to use 3/4” galvanized pipe quite often because it was also used on plumbing and we had it available if not connected to the water main. The pipe only has to be in contact with earth 10’ , driven rod 8’.

Comment: @JohnMinks -- can you *please* post photos of the hardware you have?

Comment: I can't figure out how to post photos I'm not as smart as my smart phone

Comment: I have no ground at main disconnect out at meter no ground at water pipes just that green wire going to the rv receptical  that only has 2hots and a neutral  the ground in the box isn't hooked to anything

Comment: @JohnMinks -- do you not see a button that looks like a stylized "mountain and sun" painting when you hit "edit" in "share edit ..." at the bottom left of your post?

Comment: The picture upload problem is extremely common. Everyone knows how to text or email pictures from a smartphone. Only the geeky know how to upload them. The solution would be a special email address like postid@images.stackexchange.com and then have the pictures hit a holding area for OP or another edit-rep-level user to approve/merge into the post. I've done similar stuff for my customers, but I can't change StackExchange's system. So we're as usual back to "look for mountain and sun and figure out how to upload".

Comment: @JohnMinks -- if you can't find the button, you can try uploading the pics to [imgur](https://imgur.com) and then posting a link to them in the comments here

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact -- most of the problem is with the "appliance" nature of smartphones, if you ask me -- really conditions people to *not* be looking for things beyond the predefined "bins" they provide

Comment: @JohnMinks -- we see the photo of the receptacle box at least -- can you post photos of the wiring that that RV receptacle box connects to, and also the wiring inside the mobile home's panel please?